# Recorded Audio Convert To Base 64 in android

Tags: android

how to convert Recorded Audio Convert Base 64 and uploaded to server in android studio.
i am tring this  String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP); but not working

Comment: No indeed. That will not upload.

Comment: Read [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)